# Changing textBox's content by clicking calendarMonth

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to make an agenda facility for my winform project. I want to display database records on textBox for specific date when user chose date on monthCalendar control. Below you can see my db table design, my winform design and my code and exception message that i'm getting. How can i fix this?

*ps: no need to suggest on using parametrized queries. i can and i will change it eventually

[image]

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace EKS
{
    public partial class Agenda : Form
    {
        public Agenda()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 88, 55, 55);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {

                string myQuery = "insert into agenda (input_agenda, input_date) values ('"+textBox1.Text.ToString()+"', '"+ monthCalendar1.SelectionStart +"')";

                SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
                myConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost; database=EKS; uid=sa; pwd=123; connection lifetime=20; connection timeout=25; packet size=1024;";

                SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand();
                myComm.Connection = myConn;

                myComm.CommandText = myQuery;

                myConn.Open();
                myComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConn.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("agenda updated");
            }
            catch (Exception x) {
                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM agenda WHERE input_date = '" + monthCalendar1.SelectionStart +"'";
                SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
                myConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost; database=EKS; uid=sa; pwd=123; connection lifetime=20; connection timeout=25; packet size=1024;";

                SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand();
                myComm.Connection = myConn;

                myComm.CommandText = deleteQuery;

                myConn.Open();
                myComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConn.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("delete succeeded");
            }
            catch(Exception x){
                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            GetAgendaDetails(e.Start.Date);
        }

        private void GetAgendaDetails(DateTime x){
            string myQuery = "select input_agenda from agenda where input_date = '" + x.Date.ToString() + "'";
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
            myConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost; database=EKS; uid=sa; pwd=123; connection lifetime=20; connection timeout=25; packet size=1024;";

            try {
                myConn.Open();
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery,myConn);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read()) {
                    textBox1.Text = myReader.GetString(100);
                }
                myConn.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception z){
                MessageBox.Show(z.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateSelected` event of MonthCalendar control, Which will be fired when user selects a date.

```
   private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
       AganedaInformation info = GetAgendaDetails(e.Start.Date);
    }
```

`Add a private method to query the database based on the passed selected date`

```
Private AganedaInformation GetAgendaDetails(DateTime selectedDate)
{
  //Add logic to query the database with the selected date and return the information
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio's intellisense says:
The type or namespace name 'AganedaInformation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly referance?)

Comment: @TimurAykutYıldırım :). Its just a class name i added which might return the Aganeda information to caller. If you want you can change it to void and set the textfield values within the same emethod.

Comment: i updated my code according to your advice. how can i specify parameter for GetString() method while every day's agenda content character amount is different? I also added exception's screenshot

Comment: Use myReader["ColumnName"] to get value from each column and then set it to respective textbox.